# Are cdf and pdf supposed to evaluate to the same value?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

working on a hw problem and evaluating the probability that an even happens when x < 5 using both functions is evaluating to the same answer. am I doing something wrong or is this expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you "evaluate" but actually $$\Pr(X<5)=\int_{-\infty}^5 f_X(x)dx=F_X(5)$$ where $f_X$ is pdf and $F_X$ is cdf.

Comment: I meant by evaluating the integral, and seemingly from your answer they are supposed to be the same. Thank you!